# On all non-beta sites that are subdomains of stackexchange.com, top bar image is too big

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, mobile-web, top-bar

Why does this happen on every non-beta stackexchange site (ex: [cooking.SE](http://www.cooking.stackexchange.com) and [bicycles.SE](http://www.bicycles.stackexchange.com))?

> [image: Bug picture]

but not on non-beta SE places, or non-SE subdomains like [Superuser](http://www.superuser.com) or [Stack Overflow](http://www.stackoverflow.com) like shown in this picture:

> [image: Normal picture]

Device info: iPhone 5s, mobile safari (iOS)

It might also happen on private betas, as this problem occurs on Stack Overflow in Portuguese.

Comment: Looks like this is specific profile pictures uploaded to Imgur. Gravatar images have a `width="24" height="24"` set on them.

Comment: @animuson yes, but it only has it on non-beta stackexchange sites, not places like stackoverflow

Comment: No repro. Animuson is probably right.

Comment: Might be local cache, imgur create a different image for each possible size so maybe the [24x24 version](http://i.stack.imgur.com/CsbTw.png?s=24&g=1) used on top bar was taken from cache as the [full size image](http://i.stack.imgur.com/CsbTw.png) or [128x128 version](http://i.stack.imgur.com/CsbTw.png?s=128) used in your profile page. Clear your mobile browser cache and see if it helps.

Comment: @Shadow That didn't help at all... And as I said, it only happens on SE sites, not places like SO

Comment: @ManofSnow Stack Overflow *is* Stack Exchange site. What sites exactly then?

Comment: Happens to me on stack overflow in Portuguese (private beta). And I do use gravatar.

Comment: @Shadow You see?  I me ant subdomains of SE

Comment: @ManofSnow don't think it's on all sites, for me it happens only on http://br.stackoverflow.com/ and the actual image source there ask for the 128x128 px version in the top bar.

Comment: @ShadowWizard It happens on cooking.SE, bicycles.SE, and lots of other sites

Comment: Hrm. I can't reproduce this. Gonna keep trying, though.

Comment: @AnnaLear Use an iOS 7 OS on cooking.SE and login and see what happens when you press arrow

Comment: @ManofSnow It shows up fine no matter what I try. I even tried using your avatar, and it's still showing up at the right size.

Comment: @AnnaLear Are you using imgur as the profile pic?

Comment: @ManofSnow Yes.

Comment: @AnnaLear It looks like it's fixed, because it's not happening to me anymore

Comment: Weird. I'm gonna call it status-norepro for now. Let me know if it pops back up.

Comment: @AnnaLear I don't know how to see site old versions, etc, so maybe you can take a look (because you're a community manager) and see if they fixed it (look at ux.SE, cooking.SE, etc)?

Comment: @ManofSnow Nothing relevant has changed since the mobile version of the top bar was deployed yesterday as far as I know. So this is a bit of a mystery to me.

Comment: @AnnaLear [reproduced](http://i.stack.imgur.com/20M0i.png) on http://pt.stackoverflow.com/ and quick look reveals the cause is [this chunk of HTML](http://i.stack.imgur.com/khfrU.png), the part marked with a circle. There is `?s=128` injected that cause the image to become 128x128, same size as in profile page. Can you please forward this to a dev?

Comment: @ShadowWizard Yeah, it's getting looked at.

Comment: @AnnaLear cool, hope it's Nick because he sometimes answer with true pearls of wisdom. ;-)

Comment: @ShadowWizard: What's weird is that the topbar CSS should still force the image to be scaled down to 24 by 24 pixels or less, no matter what its actual size is.

Comment: @ShadowWizard Why didn't you post the answer?  You could've had all the upvotes ;)

Comment: @ManofSnow usually in bug reports the answer belongs to the dev who fix the bug, I still can't do such a thing. :)

Comment: @IlmariKaronen nothing weird. In the full site the avatar is indeed classed as "avatar-me" which has CSS forcing 24x24 but in the mobile theme there is different HTML for the top bar and it's wrapped with "gravatar-wrapper-24" class which has no CSS rules attached to it. It's totally depending on the image actual dimensions, which are 24x24 on most sites, but as I found, not all of them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally got a repro on this. Thanks, Shadow Wizard. :)

This is an issue that only affects (some) avatars uploaded to Imgur, and it should be fixed in the next build.

Comment: Don't forget to update this answer when the next build is released :)

Comment: @ManofSnow We don't really do that. There should be a new build either tonight or tomorrow morning. We deploy pretty frequently.